# BCP through C Sharp

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

I am developing tool for inserting data from a text file to a table using csharp with bcp utility.

I used the following code,but it's not working. There is no problem with table or text file.

```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ABPROCKET\MSSQL2008R2;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True");
        string sCommandText;
        sCommandText = "exec xp_cmdShell 'bcp.exe' " + "PUBS.DBO.T1" + " IN " +@"D:\Text.Txt" + "-T" +" -c";

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = sCommandText;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("inserted");

    }
```

I think the problem is with bcp command and its parameters.somebody please help me to solve this.

Comment: What do you mean by "problem"? Are you getting errors? Unexpected behavior?

Comment: yes i'm geeting errors which says - SQL Exception unhandled "Incorrect syntax near 'PUBS' ".

Comment: Is there a reason you're calling it through T-SQL instead of just calling bcp.exe directly?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your single quote after `bcp.exe` to the end of the statement:

```
sCommandText = "exec xp_cmdShell 'bcp.exe " + "PUBS.DBO.T1" + " IN " +@"D:\Text.Txt" + "-T" +" -c'";
```

Comment: I think that fix problem ,but now it throws a new error SQL Server blocked access to procedure 'sys.xp_cmdshell' of component 'xp_cmdshell' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server. A system administrator can enable the use of 'xp_cmdshell' by using sp_configure.

Comment: By the by i am developing this tool for some non sql programmers

Comment: Well, I think that error message is pretty self-explanatory. I'm not a dba, so I couldn't help further beyond searching google or bing for instructions.

Comment: ok thanks ,one more think i like to ask is- this code work with vs express edition ? Now i'm using vs 2010 professional and i heard express edition does'nt work with remote data access.

Comment: I don't know the answer to that question, sorry.